# Python script to create a zip file with defined external packages (such as pandas)

Tags: python, aws-lambda, zip, dependency-management

Is there a way to make a python script, which creates a zip file with defined dependencies?

Something like:

```py
create_zip()
for i in ['glob', 'json', 'logging', 'pandas']:
    add_to_zip(i)
```

of course `create_zip` and `add_to_zip` functions do not exist on default and I would like to know is there a good way to define this.

Later on I would like use that zip file as layer in AWS Lambda.

Comment: what do you mean by dependencies?

Comment: external modules, packages